# Django model_set for a list of elements

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Competency(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    competencies = models.ManyToManyField(Competency, blank=True, related_name='employees')
```

From a specific skill I would like to get a queryset of employees that have competencies with that skill.

From that skill I was able to get a list of related competencies with:

```
skill = Skill.objects.get(pk=id)
competencies = skill.competency_set.all()
```

How can I do the same to create a queryset of employees given that "competencies" contains many elements?

Comment: Don't you mean `skill` contains *multiple* elements?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there is one `Skill`, and `competencies` contains multiple `Compentency`

Comment: Well `competencies` is a `QuerySet`, so it is a collection of `Competency`s (it can contain zero, one, or more elements). So that is already covered.

Comment: Yes you're right, maybe I should have excluded that last line. What I want is to get a queryset of employees from that collection of competencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, start with the model you want to get: Employee.

```
skilled_employees = Employee.objects.filter(competencies__skill=skill)
```

or just

```
skilled_employees = Employee.objects.filter(competencies__skill_id=id)
```